# Scene Line art line overlaps the colour of the Grease Pencil tool

Tags: grease-pencil

How can I fix this? The Scene Line art line overlaps the colour of the Grease Pencil tool.  Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Hello, you should be able to either put the ocean object further from the camera or the turle closer to it

Comment: No matter how far or how close, the same problem remains. thanks for the quick response.  I attach a new screenshot

Comment: @Gorgious I suspect the "scene line art" is a freestyle line art... which is an overlay after rendering, so it does not take the distance of the grease pencil object into account iirc. Or at least it does not take the distance or order of objects into account unless you change the line art settings. But I would need more info on that, since freestyle is not mentioned anywhere...

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann yup would make sense.